# Why does Drupal have both "sid" and "ssid" field in the session?

Tags: 7, sessions

Learning more about Drupal core so I can be a better contributor, understand security better, etc.

I noticed that on creating a session Drupal uses both an "sid" and "ssid" field. The code seems to indicate they are both the same (the little code I've been able to decipher so far), `'sid' && 'ssid' = session_id()`, and looking at the DB only the sid is set in my own session.

Why do both columns exist? Is it a security measure? If so what does it do? Is it a legacy field from an old system?

Looking at Drupal 7 code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a security measure; `sid` is the session id for HTTP traffic &  `ssid` is the session id for HTTPS traffic. The idea here is that secure parts of your website (e.g. **https://www.example.com/user/*/edit** ) can't be compromised by session hijacking the `sid` that occurs with HTTP traffic.

Comment: Ah yes. I see the code now that I know what I'm looking for. I always new the whole http/https shared session thing was magicy. This makes sense.